# Regexp to match string

Tags: regex

I have line like this:

```
John Smith (18 jan. 2016 y. 20:08:14):
```

What regexp will match it correctly?
I know `^[a-z ,.'-]+$` will match first and last name, but thats all I know about regex.

Comment: add `\d` for digit and `:`

Comment: Welcome to SO ! What exactly are you trying to match/capture? What programming language / editor are you using?

Comment: Try it by yourself: [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to match, but this will match the firstName, lastName, date and time, and return all these matches in capture groups:

```
/^(?<firstName>[a-z]+)\s(?<lastName>[a-z]+)\s(?:\()(?<date>[0-9]{1,2}\s[a-z]+(?:\.)\s[0-9]{4})\s(?:y\.)\s(?<time>[0-9]{2}(?::)[0-9]{2}(?::)[0-9]{2})(?:\):)$/i
```

[See the result here](https://simple-regex.com/build/57bedd7c206a2).

If you don't need to capture anything but need the string to contain this format, the regular expression will do the job as well. You may want to adjust it a bit then.